# Regular Expression for alphanumeric and some special characters not adjacent

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I would like to have a regular expression to make an Oracle SQL REGEXP_LIKE query that checks

- if a string starts with one alphanumeric character
- if the string ends with one alphanumeric character
- if the "body" of the string contains only alphanumeric character OR these authorized characters (written) : hyphen (dash), dot, apostrophe, space
- if the authorised characters are NOT adjacent (to avoid something like "he--'''l..'-lo")

I started with this :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(a-zA-Z0-9\-\.'|([^\-\.'])\1)*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

I used backslash to escape assuming that dot and hyphen are metacharacters

Comment: There would be value in you updating your question to clarify if you authorize the character, `_`.  Also, while your requirement is not bad, sample data with an indication of true or false would not hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-.' ][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])*\w?$
```

It looks for

- at least 1 alphanumeric (alnum),

followed by

- either an authorized character followed by an alphanumeric **or** just an alphanumeric, repeated any number of times (including 0).

optionally followed by

- an alnum

This meets your specification. I'm not sure if *starts with one alnum* and *ends with one alnum* means that there must be at least 2 alnums, or if they can be the same. If there must be at least 2 of them, remove the last `?` (which make the last alnum optional).

Regards

Comment: You are geniuses. Thank you both. Last question, how to obtain anything but this expression? (inverse)

Comment: I mean it returns every occurences which doesn't start with an alphanum OR doesn't end with an alphanum OR having two adjacent authorized characters OR with unauthorized character anywhere

Comment: The last ``\w`` has to be ``[:alnum:]`` (``\w`` matches also the underscore ``_``) (``[:alnum:]`` may substitute also the first ``[a-zA-Z0-9]``)

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to capture the whole expression. If oracle's regex flavor supports non capturing groups - make the repeat non capturing and place a capture group around the whole expression - `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-.' ][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]?)$`.

Comment: @GsusRecovery Right. When I experimented with the RE i used `\w` which i then replaced with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` because I didn't know if oracle could handle `\w`. Then I forgot the last one :P... But as you say, if `_` shouldn't be allowed, it should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you meant "authorised characters are NOT adjacent to each other"

try something along these lines

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\-\.' ]?)*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

so that the repeating middle part always has one alphanumeric character followed by zero to one special characters.

Comment: Posted an alternative since this one *requires at least three alphanumerics* which wasn't in the specification. But writing this comment I realize that your regex could be made to work by removing the first alphanumeric test i.e. `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\-\.' ]?)*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`.Note the last paragraph in my answer though. (However here you'd have to change `*` to a `?` to have at least 2 alnums.)